# jQuery Masonry—Constrain to a Maximum Width on Window Resize Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, max, jquery-masonry, css

I am using [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/centered.html) to display a grid of boxes (all the same size).

[Here is my testing site.](http://test.davewhitley.com/not-wp/wb/projects.php)

Works great when the browser width is 1100px or below.

When viewing it at 1270px and above, Masonry keeps adding columns on the right hand side.

I have a max-width set on the outer container, but Masonry doesn't seem to acknowledge it and just keeps expanding the width of the Masonry container.

On the [Masonry Centered page](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/centered.html), you can see that it is centered, but there is no constraining width. As you increase the browser width, it just keeps expanding and adding more columns.

How can I add a hard rule to say, "This is the maximum width. Stop trying to add more columns."

Thanks

**UPDATE**
[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26dsg/4/embedded/result), although I"m not sure if it's even set up correctly. It's best just to go to [my testing site](http://test.davewhitley.com/not-wp/wb/projects.php) to see the problem.

Comment: have you tried using the `containerStyle` option to masonry?

Comment: I included the `containerStyle` option, but it doesn't seem to read it for some reason. Right now that should put `position: absolute` on the project wrapper, but it's not.

Comment: Here is the fiddle. Not the best fiddle ever, but it works. If you can get it to not expand beyond 3 columns, you get a cookie. Don't worry about the weird hover states. http://jsfiddle.net/26dsg/4/embedded/result/

Comment: that !important seems to break your layout. Try without it.

Comment: It seems the resize issue it still happening after deleting `!important`

Comment: It may have something to do with `isFitWidth:true` and `isResizable    :true`being in the javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting a `max-width` on the parent element of the masonry'ed container works for me. Is this not the result you're looking for?

```
#wrapper { max-width: 990px; }
```